# Permission issue on windows server

Tags: windows, security

I have logged on to a windows server 2012 R2 machine with local admin account. I was trying to save a file on the hard drive but it says that I do not have permission to save file on the disk. I have checked the permission on the had drive, where administrators has full control on the drive. Please help on the issue

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder you're trying to save the file?

Comment: Did you run the application using "Run as administrator"? If not, then you are not actually an administrator (this feature is called User Account Control (UAC)).

Comment: When I run the program as administrator, I'm able to save. how to I change this feature. I have a script which runs and wants to store the log files in the hard drive, which is getting failed because of the permission issue.

Comment: Is this a powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the program as administrator, I'm able to save. how to I change this  feature. I have a script which runs and wants to store the log files in the hard drive, which is getting failed because of the permission issue.

It sounds like you have the rights, but the script is being run by a different user than local admin.  Check the script to see who it is run by in task scheduler.